# artist ID and/or translation

Tags: translation

any help with translation would be most appreciated
thank you

https://photos.app.goo.gl/EdwYUW1xTDVCEVTA6

Comment: 闲披秋水未终卷，心与天游谁得知。癸卯孟秋写于香港鹤山，吕裕中